# How to include fur in the exported obj file in Maya?

Tags: models, maya, obj

In Maya I use fur to create plants. In my game I want to render these plants with cel shading. I use Wavefront .obj as a file format in my game for the models, but it doesn't seem to include the fur.

Is there a way to export the fur (as vertices) with the model into the obj file? Generating the fur at runtime is a bit CPU expensive for the platform.

Answer (score 3):

Fur is usually implemented as a render effect -- there isn't a 1:1 correspondence with geometry, although geometry may be used to achieve the effect (textured polygonal strips, for example, or the newer and better looking '[shells and fins](http://www.gamecareerguide.com/education/theses/20051028/sheppard.pdf)' methods), so there isn't really anything to export unless you were you convert the fur representation to 3D geometry. *This would almost certainly result in extremely poor performance in your game.*

The solution you probably want to is abandon using Maya to generate the foliage and employ a rendering effect in your game code to achieve the desired results instead. The article I linked to before provides one possible implementation; [here](http://www.sgtconker.com/2009/10/article-fur-rendering/) is another example, using XNA.

However, since you said you are using Maya's fur rendering to produce plants, you may instead want to consider rendering algorithms designed for exactly that effect. Game Rendering has a whole section on "[vegetation](http://www.gamerendering.com/category/vegetation/)." There's quite a few options for grass rendering, for example:

- [Rendering Grass with Instancing in D3D10](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/rendering-grass-with-instancing-in-directx-10/)
- [Rendering Countless Blades of Waving Grass](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems/gpugems_ch07.html)

I know you mentioned being CPU limited, but you didn't specify exactly how much so, or what the GPU resources you have available are. It should be reasonable these days to implement some level of these techniques with reasonable scalability back to older hardware and without too much CPU strain.

If that fails, you can always fall back to using simple polygonal billboard strips and "exporting" your fur out of Maya by rendering it as a texture you eventually apply to the billboards in your game. But actually exporting the fur as geometry is almost certainly not the approach you want.